# Why does this implicit cast not result in compile-time error?

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

Just trying to understand C#. Just considering the following simplified example.

```
void Main()
{
    IList<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>
    {
        new Chicken(),
        new Cow(),
    };

    // Shouldn't this line result in a compile-time error?
    foreach (Chicken element in animals)
    {
    }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
}

public class Cow : IAnimal
{
}

public class Chicken : IAnimal
{
}
```

Although the first iteration succeeds, the second does not. Honestly I expected this to fail on compile time. Does anyone understand why it only fails at runtime?

Comment: [Answered by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/)

Comment: Also see: [Why does a foreach loop silently insert an “explicit” conversion?](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/) by Eric Lippert

Comment: Did someone link Eric Lippert's post about this yet?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down votes?

Comment: It's not a horrible idea to get in the habit of using `var` with `foreach` in order to avoid this type of casting (assuming you don't actually need it).

Comment: @HermanCordes  I personally did not down vote you but I would guess the down votes are for a lack of effort.  The assumption being that a google search might have gotten you the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `foreach` statement is defined in the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=7029) to have a (hidden) explicit cast:

> The above steps, if successful, unambiguously produce a collection type C, enumerator type E and element type T. A foreach statement of the form

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

> is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

(Note the `(V)(T)e.Current`, the "explicit" cast to type `V`)

It is, unfortunately, defined like this because this is what you really *needed* in C# 1 (before generics, where every collection you'd want to iterate in a `foreach` was a collection of `object`) and, now, for backwards compatibility it cannot be changed.